# Expected declaration but found '"display:none;"'. Skipped to next declaration

Tags: javascript, html

I am manipulating the DOM from JavaScript file. But I am getting this error in the console.

***Expected declaration but found '"display:none;"'.  Skipped to next declaration.***

On this line

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<textarea id=&quot;view&quot; class=&quot;span8&quot; style=&quot;display:none;&quot;></textarea>";
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<textarea id=\"view\" class=\"span8\" style=\"display:none;\"></textarea>";` - should not do html escape in javascript

Comment: or `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<textarea id="view" class="span8" style="display:none;"></textarea>';`

Comment: @ArunPJohny : You were few seconds faster :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<textarea id=\"view\" class=\"span8\" style=\"display:none;\"></textarea>"
```

or just have single quote embedding double like

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<textarea id="view" class="span8" style="display:none;"></textarea>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<textarea id='view' class='span8' style='display:none;'></textarea>"
```